# this.Close() breaks with "InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code"

Tags: c#

This is all part of a massive project, but essentially I have a welcome text box that I want to close.

The class is: `public partial class Registration : Form`

The method is: `private void Register()`

The line of code is: `this.Close();`

Why is this breaking? Do I just need to do a try/catch?

Comment: A stack trace would be good. Who is calling Register()? In what context is this happening? Has the form even been shown yet?

Comment: In Ui the most probable reason is the attempt to access the UI control from different thread / Synchronization context except Ui, check that. Please provide more details / code to debug the issue further

Comment: In search of the stack trace, I found a detail that said: `{"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Registration' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj given that the class definition inherits `Form`, wouldn't I always be in the right thread? Would changing the method to static help?

Comment: I was correct, stack trace says the same thing, What is happening is, point where you are calling `close` is part of some `thread pool thread`, which is not a `Ui thread`, hence error, options are:

1. Do that operation using `Async - Await`, then you have same `Ui context` available for update

2. Use `BackGroundWorker` to update the `Textbox` using the `Ui thread context`

Cannot suggest anything beyond W/o looking at the actual code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)